# Why the need to use enif_compare?

Tags: erlang

Why does

```
int enif_compare(ERL_NIF_TERM lhs, ERL_NIF_TERM rhs)
```

need to be used instead of just

```
if( lhs == rhs ) return 1;
```

I believe it matters that I am comparing atoms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ERL_NIF_TERM is an opaque datatype and, to the best of my knowledge, is more akin to a *pointer* than a value. In fact, here's the definition: `typedef unsigned long ERL_NIF_TERM` (technically there are a few variants, but they're all integers *with the same size as a memory address on the system*)

So, you must use enif_compare for the same reason you must use `str_cmp` when comparing C strings: the referenced values may be identical, but the values you get are not representative of that.

Consider:

```
char a[] = "test";
char b[] = "test";
printf("%d\n", a == b);
```

Logically, you and I know that the strings are identical, but the values `a` and `b` are actually pointers to the contained value. So when you do a regular compare (`==`), it's comparing the *pointers*, not the underlying value. Since they are distinct values within the function, they are allocated to different memory addresses, and as a result, `a != b`, but `str_cmp(a, b) == true`

Comment: But since they are atoms, then the ptr's should be the same, as long as on the same node, right?

Comment: **No**. The `ErlNifEnv*` you receive in NIFs is the environment of the *calling process*. If that process has previously allocated that atom then the pointers would most likely be the same, *but that is not reliable or trustworthy behavior*. The larger point here is that `ERL_NIF_TERM` is *opaque* and that you *must* use the API to interact with it. If you assume that `a == b` is valid and safe, then changes to the structure of `ERL_NIF_TERM` your code could (read: ***will***) break.

Comment: Technically, the data type returned by `queue:new` in Erlang is just `{[], []}`, but you should never replace `queue:new` with the raw tuple, because your code would stop working if they ever decided to add, say, a size field to that tuple (`{[], [], 0}`). Same logic applies here.